# Missing lxsession in the home directory cd ~/.config

Tags: pi-3, raspbian-buster, lxsession

I am running the following os image on my pi 3 model b:

Raspbian Buster with desktop and recommended software 
Image with desktop and recommended software based on Debian Buster
Version:September 2019
Release date:2019-09-26
Kernel version:4.19
Size:2541 MB

I am trying to make some modifications to the autostart file to keep the screen from going to sleep by running the command `sudo nano ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE/autostar"` but there does not exist a folder named lxsession in that directory.

Could it possibly be that there exists an lxsession but it is hidden? Please advise.

[image]

Comment: For the next time, please don't post pictures of text. Instead paste the text direct into the question :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to prevent your Pi from going into sleep mode you could just change lightdm which manages sleep mode.

Go into the config file:

```
sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

and add the following line:

```
xserver-command=X -s 0 dpms
```

Edit:
I just noticed you're probably following a guide for the Raspberry Pi 4 where indeed that directory and file exist. But the Pi 3/3b need another approach if you want to get something into auto start.

Regarding your missing directory I think that you are searching for:

```
/home/pi/.config/autostart
```

and there you need to create a file which does what you need it to do but I only created .desktop files, so I'm not quite sure what type of file you need.(Probably a .desktop file that executes some command)